# GPRC Android genearted code has unresolved references

Tags: android, kotlin, protocol-buffers, grpc

I'm using GPRC and Protobuf to generate code. They do generate but I get these errors:

```
> Task :app:compileDebugKotlin FAILED
e:/path/to/generated/code/MyGrpcKt.kt: (16, 16): Unresolved reference: kotlin
e:/path/to/generated/code/MyGrpcKt.kt: (17, 16): Unresolved reference: kotlin
e:/path/to/generated/code/MyGrpcKt.kt: (18, 16): Unresolved reference: kotlin
e:/path/to/generated/code/MyGrpcKt.kt: (19, 16): Unresolved reference: kotlin
e:/path/to/generated/code/MyGrpcKt.kt: (20, 16): Unresolved reference: kotlin
e:/path/to/generated/code/MyGrpcKt.kt: (21, 16): Unresolved reference: kotlin
e:/path/to/generated/code/MyGrpcKt.kt: (22, 16): Unresolved reference: kotlin
e:/path/to/generated/code/MyGrpcKt.kt: (39, 48): Unresolved reference: Cookie
e:/path/to/generated/code/MyGrpcKt.kt: (43, 51): Unresolved reference: Cookie
e:/path/to/generated/code/MyGrpcKt.kt: (50, 4): Unresolved reference: StubFor
e:/path/to/generated/code/MyGrpcKt.kt: (54, 7): Unresolved reference: AbstractCoroutineStub
e:/path/to/generated/code/MyGrpcKt.kt: (55, 5): 'build' overrides nothing
e:/path/to/generated/code/MyGrpcKt.kt: (68, 44): Unresolved reference: Cookie
e:/path/to/generated/code/MyGrpcKt.kt: (68, 65): Unresolved reference: unaryRpc
e:/path/to/generated/code/MyGrpcKt.kt: (69, 7): Unresolved reference: channel
e:/path/to/generated/code/MyGrpcKt.kt: (72, 7): Unresolved reference: callOptions
e:/path/to/generated/code/MyGrpcKt.kt: (85, 47): Unresolved reference: Cookie
e:/path/to/generated/code/MyGrpcKt.kt: (85, 68): Unresolved reference: unaryRpc
e:/path/to/generated/code/MyGrpcKt.kt: (86, 7): Unresolved reference: channel
e:/path/to/generated/code/MyGrpcKt.kt: (89, 7): Unresolved reference: callOptions
e:/path/to/generated/code/MyGrpcKt.kt: (98, 7): Unresolved reference: AbstractCoroutineServerImpl
e:/path/to/generated/code/MyGrpcKt.kt: (110, 49): Unresolved reference: Cookie
e:/path/to/generated/code/MyGrpcKt.kt: (124, 52): Unresolved reference: Cookie
e:/path/to/generated/code/MyGrpcKt.kt: (127, 11): 'bindService' overrides nothing
e:/path/to/generated/code/MyGrpcKt.kt: (128, 8): Not enough information to infer type variable ReqT
e:/path/to/generated/code/MyGrpcKt.kt: (128, 18): Unresolved reference: unaryServerMethodDefinition
e:/path/to/generated/code/MyGrpcKt.kt: (129, 22): Unresolved reference: context
e:/path/to/generated/code/MyGrpcKt.kt: (133, 8): Not enough information to infer type variable ReqT
e:/path/to/generated/code/MyGrpcKt.kt: (133, 18): Unresolved reference: unaryServerMethodDefinition
e: /path/to/generated/code/MyGrpcKt.kt: (134, 22): Unresolved reference: context

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

This is my build.gradle (app)

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'com.google.protobuf'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
apply plugin: 'idea'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}


android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId “com.my.id”
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
}

sourceSets {
    main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/javalite'
}

protobuf {
    protoc {
        artifact = "com.google.protobuf:protoc:3.17.2"
    }
    plugins {
        grpc {
            artifact = "io.grpc:protoc-gen-grpc-java:1.38.0"
        }
        grpckt {
            artifact = "io.grpc:protoc-gen-grpc-kotlin:1.1.0:jdk7@jar"
        }
    }
    generateProtoTasks {
        all().forEach {
            it.plugins {
                grpc {
                    option("lite")
                }
                grpckt {
                    option("lite")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.5.10"
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.5.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:$lifecycle_version"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:$lifecycle_version"
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'

    // Test
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    testImplementation 'androidx.arch.core:core-testing:2.1.0'
    testImplementation "io.mockk:mockk:1.11.0"

    // Firebase
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:26.7.0')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth-ktx'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore-ktx'

    // GRPC
    implementation "io.grpc:grpc-okhttp:$grpc"
    implementation "io.grpc:grpc-stub:$grpc"
    compileOnly 'org.apache.tomcat:annotations-api:6.0.53'

    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-play-services:1.5.0-native-mt'

}
```

And my build.gradle (module)

```
ext {
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
buildscript {

    ext {
        kotlin_version = '1.5.10'
        nav_version = '2.3.5'
        hilt_version = '2.36'
        lifecycle_version = '2.3.1'
        grpc = '1.38.0'
        protobuf = '3.14.0'
        grpcKotlinVersion = '1.1.0'
    }

    repositories {
        google()
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.5.10'
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.8'
        classpath "com.google.protobuf:protobuf-gradle-plugin:0.8.16"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Any ideas welcome! Or if you need more info, please ask :)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I changed the generateProtoTasks section to this and then it built. Not sure why though. Please add a comment if you know!

```
generateProtoTasks {
    all().each { task ->
        task.builtins {
            remove javanano
            java {
                option 'lite'
            }
        }

        task.plugins {
            grpc {
                // Options added to --grpc_out
                option 'lite'
            }
        }
    }
}
```